# Is there a character that is the same size as a bullet, but open?

Tags: ascii, character

I'm looking for a character that is just like • but an open circle (Maybe even a bigger bullet and it's open counterpart.) Does anybody know if there are such characters?

Comment: which character set you are talking about ? ascii ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you could use [BULLET](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm) (U+2022) and [WHITE BULLET](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25e6/index.htm) (U+25E6):

```
• Bullet
◦ White Bullet
```

Comment: I just noticed that you tagged ASCII. These aren't ASCII characters but Unicode characters. I hope that's OK.

Comment: Actually I am a kid, and I do call tables of characters ASCII. I understand the differences and things. I actually wasn't 100% that these chars. were unicode or if they were region specific by some chance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at http://www.asciitable.com/ you see some circles in the extended ascii part. (e.g. 167, 248)

Answer (score 0):

String name = Character.toString((char)8226);

System.out.println("name "+name);

will work fine in java

Answer (score 0):

Use this ([COM­BI­NING ENCLOSING CIRCLE](http://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=CIRCLE)): ⃝

Answer (score -1):

There's ASCII 186 which is the masculine ordinal indicator, or you can use the degree sign which is ASCII 176.